# How to change a tabbar after performing a segue transition

Tags: swift2, ios9

I have run into a problem. After trying to segue (actually unwind a segue), I want to programmatically move to a different tab (user start an action from the front tab, is segued to a modal view and does his/her tasks, after finishing the modal view is unwound, then I want to give the user feedback and present it in the last tab (so the user can start a new action after that or come back to the feedback again later).

`@IBAction func backToSimulatorView(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
      self.ToFeedback(segue)
}`

When I add a button in the same viewcontroller and do this action, it works just fine:

```
@IBAction func ToFeedback(sender: AnyObject) {
  let tc = self.tabBarController! as UITabBarController
  tc.selectedIndex = 2
}
```

This code does not work:

`@IBAction func backToSimulatorView(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
      self.ToFeedback(segue)
      let tc = self.tabBarController! as UITabBarController
      tc.selectedIndex = 2
}`

I could probably work around it using a notification but that feels a bit like a hack.

Comment: You can have a callback or delegation pattern. you have to hook the back action in navigation bar means by  giving your implementation for back navigation

Comment: Thanks Prabhu. You have helped me solve the problem. I think the issue with my initial strategy was that the order of events is not as I expected. The index might be changed but is right after that reset to index 0 because of the unwind to that initial view.

I now have implemented a check in the viewController viewWillAppear method and if the bool is true it will move to the other tab: so a kind of call back.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the callback mechanism, In FirstViewController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    //object ref, we need to set the callback property of destination view controller
    SecondViewController *svc = (SecondViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];

    [svc setMyCallBack:^(NSString *dat) {
        NSLog(@"%@", dat); //Prints the data posted back by Secondviewcontroller.
    }];
}
```

In SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

- (void)setMyCallBack:(MyNewCallBack)cb; //First view controller sets the callback through this method.

@end
```

In SecondViewController.m

```
@interface SecondViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong)MyNewCallBack mycb;// we need this property to access the callback where ever we need.
@end

- (IBAction)NavigationBarBackAction:(id)sender {
    self.mycb(@"MyData"); // Here i am passing a string to First View Controller.
}

- (void)setMyCallBack:(MyNewCallBack)cb {
    self.mycb = cb;
}
```

I Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the mechanism, that is Objective C though, I use Swift 2.1.

Comment: don you know how to convert Obj C to swift?

Comment: Hello. The question is tagged "swift", please provide an answer in Swift, not in another language. Thanks!